# maximumRateMsgsPerSec doesn't change (IBM App Connect)

Tags: rate-limiting, ibm-integration-bus, ibm-app-connect

We try to make a property which could be changed by users in IBM App Connect. We create an application RateLimit, which should change maximumRateMsgsPerSec.
[RateLimit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KEPZ.png)

We can override The Local UDP: maximumRateMsgsPerSec property.
It changes in ‘User-defined property’ block,

```
User-defined property               Persisted value Override Active value
Local UDP: maximumRateMsgsPerSec    1               12       12
```

but the Active value stays the same in ‘Property block’.

```
Property                           Persisted value Active value
Maximum rate (messages per second) 1               -
```

IBM sayd :
Additionally, once the BAR file is deployed, the property can be set dynamically within the flow through the IBM Integration API. Any change to the property is picked up immediately and does not require the flow to be restarted. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/11.0.0?topic=management-setting-maximum-rate-message-flow

But it doesn’t work.  How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `maximumRateMsgsPerSec` is a [Workload Management](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/12.0?topic=properties-workload-management-policy-workloadmanagement) property, not a User Defined Property.

The chapter [Configuring workload management policies by using the IBM Integration API](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=caop-configuring-workload-management-policies-by-using-integration-api) describes how you can change this value at runtime.